# Personalized Sizeable Arrow

Tags: arrows

[image: personalized sizeable arrow]

I want to know how to draw a personalized sizeable arrow in latex like the one in the picture (ignore the portuguese sentences).

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, fleqn] {article}
\usepackage [portuguese] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\pagestyle {plain}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

{\flushleft

13)

\vspace{10px}

\begin{align*}
 y(t) = \text{?}
\end{align*}

\vspace{30px}

sabendo que

\begin{align}
 & H(p) = \dfrac{(p + 3)}{(p^{2} + 3p + 2)}  \\
 & y(0^{-}) = 1  \\
 & y'(0^{-}) = 2  \\
 & f(t) = u(t)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

(i) por convolução

\vspace{30px}

Sabe-se, por definição, que

\begin{align}
 y(t) = y_{o}(t) + y_{x}(t) 
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

onde

\begin{align*}
 y_{o}(t) \rightarrow \text{resposta à entrada zero}  \\
 y_{x}(t) \rightarrow \text{resposta ao estado zero}
\end{align*}

\vspace{30px}

De (1), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 (D^{2} + 3D + 2)y(t) = (D + 3)f(t)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

De (6), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 (\lambda^{2} + 3\lambda + 2) = 0
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Logo,

\begin{align}
 & (\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 2) = 0 \nonumber  \\
 & \lambda = -1  \\
 & \lambda = -2 
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

De (8) e de (9), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{o}(t) = c_{1}e^{-t} + c_{2}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Derivando (10), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{o}'(t) = -c_{1}e^{-t} - 2c_{2}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (2) em (10), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & c_{1}e^{-(0)} + c_{2}e^{-2(0)} = 1 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{2} = 1 - c_{1}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (3) e (12) em (11), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & -c_{1}e^{-(0)} - 2(1 - c_{1})e^{-2(0)} = 2 \nonumber  \\
 & -c_{1} - 2 + 2c_{1} = 2 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{1} = 4
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (13) em (12), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 c_{2} & = 1 - 4 \nonumber  \\
       & = -3
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (13) e (14) em (10), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{o}(t) = 4e^{-t} - 3e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Sabe-se, pelo Método do Casamento do Impulso, que

\begin{align}
 h(t) = [P(D)y_{m}(t)]\;u(t),\quad (M < N)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

sendo

\begin{align}
 & y_{m}(0) = y'_{m}(0) = y''_{m}(0) = ... = y^{(N - 2)}_{m}(0) = 0 \\
 & y^{(N - 1)}_{m}(0) = 1
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Como $N = 2$, tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & y_{m}(0) = 0  \\
 & y'_{m}(0) = 1  \\
 & y_{m}(t) = c_{3}e^{-t} + c_{4}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Derivando (21), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & y'_{m}(t) = -c_{3}e^{-t} + -2c_{4}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (19) em (21), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & c_{3}e^{-(0)} + c_{4}e^{-2(0)} = 0 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{4} = -c_{3}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (20) e (23) em (22), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & -c_{3}e^{-(0)} + -2(-c_{3})e^{-2(0)} = 1 \nonumber  \\
 & -c_{3} + 2c_{3} = 1 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{3} = 1
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (24) em (23), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 c_{4} & = -(1) \nonumber  \\
       & = -1
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (24) e (25) em (21), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{m}(t) = e^{-t} - e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

De (6), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 P(D) = D + 3
\end{align}

\vspace{130px}

Substituindo (26) e (27) em (16), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 h(t) & = [(D + 3)(e^{-t} - e^{-2t})]\;u(t) \nonumber  \\
      & = [D(e^{-t} - e^{-2t}) + 3(e^{-t} - e^{-2t})]\;u(t) \nonumber  \\
      & = (-e^{-t} + 2e^{-2t} + 3e^{-t} - 3e^{-2t})\;u(t) \nonumber  \\
      & = (2e^{-t} - e^{-2t})\;u(t)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Sabe-se, por definição, que

\begin{align}
 y_{x}(t) & = f(t) * h(t) \nonumber  \\
          & = h(t) * f(t) \nonumber  \\
          & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(\tau)\;f(t - \tau) \; d\tau
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

Substituindo (4) e (28) em (29), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{x}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(2e^{-\tau} - 
 e^{-2\tau})\;u(\tau)\;u(t - \tau) \; d\tau
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}

De (30), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 & (2e^{-\tau} - e^{-2\tau})\;u(\tau) = 0, \quad (\tau < 0)  \\
 & u(t - \tau) = 0, \quad (\tau > t)
\end{align}

\vspace{150px}

Separando a análise de (31) e (32) em dois casos, tem-se que

\begin{align*}
 & \text{1 caso:} \; t < 0  \\ \\
 & \xrightarrow{\hspace*{10cm}}\tau  \\ \\
 & \text{2 caso:} \; t > 0  \\ \\
 & \xrightarrow{\hspace*{10cm}}\tau
\end{align*}

\vspace{30px}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! isn't it more simple draw this arrow as picture (tikz, pstrick)? please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko this qould be the best route. With tikz it should be no issue to make a new arrow and even give it optional length, head size, or size it as a whole. From the drawing it looks like a simple arrow. Downside is that tikz might be daunting at first

Comment: Now I've inserted the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

see if the following `tikz` (fancy) solution i is usable to you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% temporary fix
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g__prg_map_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
% end of temporary fix
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
LH/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=between
                positions 0.01 and 1 step 4mm with
                {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);}},
             postaction={decorate}
             },
RH/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=between
                positions 0.01 and 1 step 4mm with
                {\draw (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}},
             postaction={decorate}
             },
BC/.style = {decorate,
              decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
              raise=3mm, #1},% for mirroring of brace
              thick, pen colour={red}
},
                        ]
\draw[LH] (0,0) -- (0.6\linewidth,0);
\draw[RH] (\linewidth,0) node[below=2mm] {$\tau\to$} -- (0.4\linewidth,0);
\draw   (0.4\linewidth,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {$t$};
\draw   (0.6\linewidth,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {$0$};
\draw[BC]   (0,0) --
    node[above=5mm] {$(2\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}- 2\mathrm{e}^{-2\tau})u(\tau)$}
            (0.6\linewidth,0);
\draw[BC]   (\linewidth,-4mm) --
    node[below=5mm] {$u(t-\tau)$}
            (0.4\linewidth,-4mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```