# Personalized Sizeable Arrow (Continuation)

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

In another question ([Personalized Sizeable Arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452718/personalized-sizeable-arrow)), I had asked how to make a personalized arrow (for the first case in this code), but I can't make it right for the second case (as in the photo).

[image: Personalized Sizeable Arrow]

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, fleqn] {article}



\usepackage [portuguese] {babel}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}

\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage {amsmath}




% temporary fix
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g__prg_map_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
% end of temporary fix

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,
            decorations.pathreplacing,
            calligraphy}












\pagestyle {plain}

\pagenumbering{gobble}





\begin{document}

{\flushleft


13)

\vspace{10px}





\begin{align*}
 y(t) = \text{?}
\end{align*}

\vspace{30px}





sabendo que

\begin{align}
 & H(p) = \dfrac{(p + 3)}{(p^{2} + 3p + 2)}  \\
 & y(0^{-}) = 1  \\
 & y'(0^{-}) = 2  \\
 & f(t) = u(t)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





(i) por convolução

\vspace{30px}





Sabe-se, por definição, que

\begin{align}
 y(t) = y_{o}(t) + y_{x}(t) 
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





onde

\begin{align*}
 y_{o}(t) \rightarrow \text{resposta à entrada zero}  \\
 y_{x}(t) \rightarrow \text{resposta ao estado zero}
\end{align*}

\vspace{30px}





De (1), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 (D^{2} + 3D + 2)y(t) = (D + 3)f(t)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





De (6), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 (\lambda^{2} + 3\lambda + 2) = 0
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Logo,

\begin{align}
 & (\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 2) = 0 \nonumber  \\
 & \lambda = -1  \\
 & \lambda = -2 
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





De (8) e de (9), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{o}(t) = c_{1}e^{-t} + c_{2}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Derivando (10), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{o}'(t) = -c_{1}e^{-t} - 2c_{2}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (2) em (10), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & c_{1}e^{-(0)} + c_{2}e^{-2(0)} = 1 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{2} = 1 - c_{1}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (3) e (12) em (11), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & -c_{1}e^{-(0)} - 2(1 - c_{1})e^{-2(0)} = 2 \nonumber  \\
 & -c_{1} - 2 + 2c_{1} = 2 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{1} = 4
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (13) em (12), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 c_{2} & = 1 - 4 \nonumber  \\
       & = -3
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (13) e (14) em (10), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{o}(t) = 4e^{-t} - 3e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Sabe-se, pelo Método do Casamento do Impulso, que

\begin{align}
 h(t) = [P(D)y_{m}(t)]\;u(t),\quad (M < N)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





sendo

\begin{align}
 & y_{m}(0) = y'_{m}(0) = y''_{m}(0) = ... = y^{(N - 2)}_{m}(0) = 0  \\
 & y^{(N - 1)}_{m}(0) = 1
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Como $N = 2$, tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & y_{m}(0) = 0  \\
 & y'_{m}(0) = 1  \\
 & y_{m}(t) = c_{3}e^{-t} + c_{4}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Derivando (21), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & y'_{m}(t) = -c_{3}e^{-t} + -2c_{4}e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (19) em (21), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & c_{3}e^{-(0)} + c_{4}e^{-2(0)} = 0 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{4} = -c_{3}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (20) e (23) em (22), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 & -c_{3}e^{-(0)} + -2(-c_{3})e^{-2(0)} = 1 \nonumber  \\
 & -c_{3} + 2c_{3} = 1 \nonumber  \\
 & c_{3} = 1
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (24) em (23), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 c_{4} & = -(1) \nonumber  \\
       & = -1
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (24) e (25) em (21), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{m}(t) = e^{-t} - e^{-2t}
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





De (6), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 P(D) = D + 3
\end{align}

\vspace{130px}





Substituindo (26) e (27) em (16), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 h(t) & = [(D + 3)(e^{-t} - e^{-2t})]\;u(t) \nonumber  \\
      & = [D(e^{-t} - e^{-2t}) + 3(e^{-t} - e^{-2t})]\;u(t) \nonumber  \\
      & = (-e^{-t} + 2e^{-2t} + 3e^{-t} - 3e^{-2t})\;u(t) \nonumber  \\
      & = (2e^{-t} - e^{-2t})\;u(t)
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Sabe-se, por definição, que

\begin{align}
 y_{x}(t) & = f(t) * h(t) \nonumber  \\
          & = h(t) * f(t) \nonumber  \\
          & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(\tau)\;f(t - \tau) \; d\tau
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





Substituindo (4) e (28) em (29), tem-se que

\begin{align}
 y_{x}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(2e^{-\tau} - e^{-2\tau})\;u(\tau)\;u(t - \tau) \; d\tau
\end{align}

\vspace{30px}





De (30), deduz-se que

\begin{align}
 & (2e^{-\tau} - e^{-2\tau})\;u(\tau) = 0, \quad (\tau < 0)  \\
 & u(t - \tau) = 0, \quad (\tau > t)
\end{align}

\vspace{150px}





Separando a análise de (31) e (32) em dois casos, tem-se que

\begin{align*}
 \text{1\si{\degree} caso:} \; t < 0
\end{align*}

\vspace{20px}





\begin{tikzpicture}[
 LH/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=between
            positions 0.01 and 1 step 4mm with
            {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);}},
         postaction={decorate}
         },
 RH/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=between
            positions 0.01 and 1 step 4mm with
            {\draw (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}},
         postaction={decorate}
         },
 BC/.style = {decorate,
          decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
          raise=3mm, #1},% for mirroring of brace
          thick, pen colour={blue}
},
                    ]
\draw[LH] (0,0) -- (0.6\linewidth,0);
\draw[RH] (\linewidth,0) node[below=2mm] {$\tau\to$} -- 
(0.4\linewidth,0);
\draw   (0.4\linewidth,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {$t$};
\draw   (0.6\linewidth,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {$0$};
\draw[BC]   (0,0) --
    node[above=5mm] {$(2\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}- 2\mathrm{e}^{-2\tau})u(\tau)$}
        (0.6\linewidth,0);
\draw[BC]   (\linewidth,-4mm) --
node[below=5mm] {$u(t-\tau)$}
        (0.4\linewidth,-4mm);
\end{tikzpicture}





\begin{align*}
 \text{2\si{\degree} caso:} \; t > 0
\end{align*}

\vspace{20px}





\begin{tikzpicture}[
 LH/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=between
            positions 0.01 and 1 step 4mm with
            {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);}},
         postaction={decorate}
         },
 RH/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=between
            positions 0.01 and 1 step 4mm with
            {\draw (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}},
         postaction={decorate}
         },
 BC/.style = {decorate,
          decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
          raise=3mm, #1},% for mirroring of brace
          thick, pen colour={blue}
},
                    ]
\draw[LH] (0,0) -- (0.4\linewidth,0);
\draw[RH] (\linewidth,0) node[below=2mm] {$\tau\to$} -- (0.4\linewidth,0);
\draw   (0.4\linewidth,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {$0$};
\draw   (0.6\linewidth,2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below] {$t$};
\draw[BC]   (0,0) --
node[above=5mm] {$(2\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}- 2\mathrm{e}^{-2\tau})u(\tau)$}
        (0.4\linewidth,0);
\draw[BC]   (\linewidth,-4mm) --
node[below=5mm] {$u(t-\tau)$}
        (0.6\linewidth,-4mm);
\end{tikzpicture}







}






\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't get me wrong, but your code is not really minimal. And you may be surprised that, in order to get something like your screen shot, you may not need any of the libraries you load. Here is something that is more minimal and arguably reproduces your screen shot rather closely.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,0) -- (6,0) node[below] {$\tau$};
\draw[thick] (0,0.25) -- (0,-0.25) node[below] {$0$};
\draw[thick] (2,0.25) -- (2,-0.25) node[below] {$t$};
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (-4,-0.1) rectangle (0,0.1);
\fill[pattern=north west lines] (2,-0.1) rectangle (6,0.1);
\node[anchor=west] (legenda) at (-4,-1) {legenda};
\node[below=3mm of legenda.south west, anchor=west,pattern=north east lines,
minimum width=2cm,minimum height=4mm] (legenda1){};
\node[below=3mm of legenda1.south west, anchor=west,pattern=north west lines,
minimum width=2cm,minimum height=4mm] (legenda2){};
\draw[-latex] (legenda1.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[right]{$\left(2\mathrm{e}^{-\tau}
-\mathrm{e}^{-2\tau}\right)\mu(\tau)=0$};
\draw[-latex] (legenda2.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[right]{$\mu\left(t-\tau\right)=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will be able to insert the `tikzpicture`, i.e. the stuff starting with `\begin{tikzpicture}` and ending with `\end{tikzpicture}`, into your document provided you add `\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning}` into your preamble, i.e. somewhere between `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\begin{document}`.